# spaCy add_pipe() and analyze_pipes() error

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to spaCy and I need help with the following errors. I pretty much grab the code from [the spaCy website](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines). It works on its website but not in my jupyternotebook.

1. When I ran the following code:

   import spacy

   nlp = spacy.blank("en")
   nlp.add_pipe("tagger")

I have the following error:

> ValueError: [E003] Not a valid pipeline component. Expected callable, but got 'tagger' (name: 'None').[E004] If you meant to add a built-in component, use `create_pipe`: `nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('tagger'))`

2. When I ran the following code:

   import spacy

   nlp = spacy.blank("en")
   nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe("tagger"))
   nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe("entity_linker"))
   analysis = nlp.analyze_pipes(pretty=True)

I received the following error:

> AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'analyze_pipes'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your notebook is using spaCy v2, but the website is for spaCy v3, which was released over a year ago. You should upgrade spaCy. For example with pip you can do `pip install -U spacy`.